# What is the purpose of the SignIn and SignOut methods in ControllerBase?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

What is the purpose of the [`SignIn`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L993) and [`SignOut`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L1018) methods in the [`ControllerBase`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs) class (which is inherited by the `Controller` class).

These two methods return a [`SignInResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/SignInResult.cs) and a [`SignOutResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/SignOutResult.cs) respectively, both which inherit from the base class [`ActionResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ActionResult.cs) (which implements `IActionResult`).

Looking up the source code for `SignInResult` and `SignOutResult` you see they call [`HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/067eb9c6f80cd2e50fdf3b3d1af0fbd94ac7bc33/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationManager.cs#L150) and [`HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/067eb9c6f80cd2e50fdf3b3d1af0fbd94ac7bc33/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationManager.cs#L150) respectively.

But I have never seen these two methods used anywhere. If you look at the `AccountController` then it signs in and out using a `ApplicationSignInManager`, not the above mentioned methods.

Since these are `ActionResult`, it leads me to believe these are to be used as the return value of actions in the controller.

Such as something like this for example:

```cs
public IActionResult SignIn()
{
    return SignIn(User, "Automatic");
}
```

But this apparently does nothing. It doesn't seem to sign in the user, and it doesn't seem to return anything to the user. I am not sure what parameters to pass, but I found `User` (from `HttpContext` in the controller).

So what is the purpose of these two methods, and how are they intended to be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AccountController uses ASP.Identity, which in turn, underneath the hood does call `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync()`

They're a convenience for folks who don't want to use ASP.NET Identity and who want to do everything themselves.

Comment: I see. Do you know why it returns nothing? Or how to use it? What parameters to specify, etc.

Comment: Honestly if you're asking that, it's not for you. This isn't being mean, it's one of those interesting security interface points where you shouldn't use it unless you fully understand it and how signin and authentication middleware hangs together. There is documentation on how to use cookie middleware without identity, which uses context directly, https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html, but for the majority of folks, it's not something you want to end up doing.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to the `SignIn` method is the `AuthenticationScheme` string.

This string can be:

- "Bearer"
- "Cookies"
- "OpenIdConnect"

Or if using third-party authentication providers:

- "Google"
- "Facebook"
- "Microsoft"
- "Twitter"

Instead of passing this parameter as a hard-coded string, you can use a constant.

- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerDefaults.cs)
- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationDefaults.cs)
- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectDefaults.cs)
- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleDefaults.cs)
- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookDefaults.cs)
- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter.TwitterDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter/TwitterDefaults.cs)
- [`AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/MicrosoftAccountDefaults.cs)

If you have some other third-party authentication provider the `AuthenticationScheme` string can be something else. Also some authentication providers (such as the `UseCookieAuthentication` middleware) lets you specify the `AuthenticationScheme`.